# How to build minified and uncompressed bundle with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

  entry: "./entry.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
  ]
};
```

I'm building with

```
$ webpack
```

In my `dist` folder, I'm only getting

- `bundle.min.js`
- `bundle.min.js.map`

I'd also like to see the uncompressed `bundle.js`

Answer (score 170, accepted):

*webpack.config.js*:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle": "./entry.js",
    "bundle.min": "./entry.js",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
      minimize: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Since Webpack 4, `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` has been deprecated and its use results in error:

> webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead

As [the manual](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/) explains, the plugin can be replaced with `minimize` option. Custom configuration can be provided to the plugin by specifying `UglifyJsPlugin` instance:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/
    })]
  }
};
```

This does the job for a simple setup. A more effective solution is to use Gulp together with Webpack and do the same thing in one pass.

Comment: @FeloVilches I don't even mention that this is done in webpack.config.js, but this is presumed once we are in Node.js land and use Webpack.

Comment: Hmm, in **webpack 4** i got: `Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.`

Comment: Update: now you can use terser-webpack-plugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/

Answer (score 168):

You can use a single config file, and include the UglifyJS plugin conditionally using an environment variable:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_ENV || '0');

module.exports = {

  entry: './entry.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: PROD ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: PROD,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({ parallel: true })
  ]
};
```

and then just set this variable when you want to minify it:

```
$ PROD_ENV=1 webpack
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments, `NODE_ENV` is generally used (by convention) to state whether a particular environment is a production or a development environment. To check it, you can also set `const PROD = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')`, and continue normally.

Comment: Node has one "default" variable for that, it's called NODE_ENV.

Comment: Isn't the option called `compress` instead of `minimize`?

Comment: Just a small gotcha: when you call webpack with arguments, like `webpack -p` the settings from _webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin_ in your webpack config **will be (at least partially) ignored** (at least setting `mangle: false` is ignored).

Comment: Notice that this generates only one file at a time. So in order to make this work for the question there should be multiple Webpack passes, `webpack && webpack -p`.

Comment: What is the reason behind writing `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` instead of just `new UglifyJsPlugin()`? UglifyJS will minify code, and so does webpack.optimize I beleive..

Comment: is there a way to generate both files with a single `webpack` command?

Comment: For anyone reading this, I would suggest using [`definePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) instead, which I think is installed by default with Webpack.

Comment: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed since v4, please use config.optimization.minimize instead

Comment: [Instead of "edit:"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) I'd just update the code to use `NODE_ENV`. There's no need to keep an old, clearly suboptimal, version in the answer text for posterity. It's there in the history should anyone need it.

Answer (score 57):

You can run webpack twice with different arguments:

```
$ webpack --minimize
```

then check command line arguments in `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path'),
  webpack = require('webpack'),
  minimize = process.argv.indexOf('--minimize') !== -1,
  plugins = [];

if (minimize) {
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
}

...
```

example [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/gfdev/javascript-jquery-transport-xdr/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Comment: Seems very simple solution to me; just that as of webpack v3.5.5 it has built-in switch called --optimize-minimize or -p.

Comment: The idea is cool, but not work now,  webpack will yell "Unknown argument: minimize"
Solution: use  --env.minimize
more details in the following link  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2254

Comment: Can use more standard way to pass environment indication in webpack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113359/passing-command-line-arguments-to-webpack-config-js

Answer (score 41):

To add another answer, the flag `-p` (short for `--optimize-minimize`) will enable the UglifyJS with default arguments.

You won't get a minified and raw bundle out of a single run or generate differently named bundles so the `-p` flag may not meet your use case.

Conversely the `-d` option is short for `--debug` `--devtool sourcemap` `--output-pathinfo`

My webpack.config.js omits `devtool`, `debug`, `pathinfo`, and the minmize plugin in favor of these two flags.

Comment: Thanks @everett1992 , this solution works great.  The vast majority of the time I run the dev build, then when I'm done I use the -p flag to spit out a minified production build.  No need to create two separate Webpack configs!

Answer (score 38):

Maybe i am late here, but i have the same issue, so i wrote a [unminified-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/leftstick/unminified-webpack-plugin) for this purpose.

**Installation**

```
npm install --save-dev unminified-webpack-plugin
```

**Usage**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var UnminifiedWebpackPlugin = require('unminified-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'library.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new UnminifiedWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};
```

By doing as above, you will get two files library.min.js and library.js. No need execute webpack twice, it just works!^^

Comment: This plugin seems to not be compatible with SourceMapDevToolPlugin. Any suggestions to retain source maps?

Comment: @BhavikUp, it's not supported. Do you think you really need source map to be output along with the final js file?

Comment: "No need to execute webpack twice [...]" Nice, but [estus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34018909/1906307)'s solution also does not require to "execute webpack twice" and additionally does not require adding a third-party plugin.

Comment: @Howard Man, you're right on time :). At least, for me. Thanks a lot for the great plug-in! Seems to work perfectly with webpack 2 and -p option.

Answer (score 36):

In my opinion it's a **lot** easier just to use the [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) tool directly:

1. `npm install --save-dev uglify-js`
2. Use webpack as normal, e.g. building a `./dst/bundle.js` file.
3. Add a `build` command to your `package.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "build": "webpack && uglifyjs ./dst/bundle.js -c -m -o ./dst/bundle.min.js --source-map ./dst/bundle.min.js.map"
   }
   ```
4. Whenever you want to build a your bundle as well as uglified code and sourcemaps, run the `npm run build` command.

No need to install uglify-js globally, just install it locally for the project.

Comment: yes this is an easy solution that allows you to build only once

Answer (score 16):

You can create two configs for webpack, one that minifies the code and one that doesn't (just remove the optimize.UglifyJSPlugin line) and then run both configurations at the same time `$ webpack && webpack --config webpack.config.min.js`

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but it sure would be nice if there was a better way to do this than to maintain two config files given that this is such a common use case (just about any library build).

Answer (score 12):

According with this line: https://github.com/pingyuanChen/webpack-uglify-js-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L117

should be something like:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

  entry: "./entry.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
     minimize: true,
     compress: false
    })
  ]
};
```

Indeed you can have multiple builds by exporting different configs according your env / argv strategies.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer on an aged-but-somehow-still-relevant question, Mauro ^_^

Comment: Can't find option `minimize` in docs. Perhaps it's deprecated?

Comment: @adi518 Maybe you are using a newer version of the plugin and not the one, bundled within webpack?

Answer (score 9):

I found a new solution for this problem.

This uses an array of configuration to enable webpack to build the minified and non-minified version in parallel. This make build faster. No need to run the webpack twice. No need extra plugins. Just webpack.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const devConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: { bundle: './src/entry.js' },
  output: { filename: '[name].js' },
  module: { ... },
  resolve: { ... },
  plugins: { ... }
};

const prodConfig = {
  ...devConfig,
  mode: 'production',
  output: { filename: '[name].min.js' }
};

module.exports = (env) => {
  switch (env) {
    case 'production':
      return [devConfig, prodConfig];
    default:
      return devConfig;
  }
};
```

Running `webpack` will only build the non-minified version.

Running `webpack --env=production` will build the minified and non-minified version at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

```
webpack entry.jsx ./output.js -p
```

works for me, with `-p` flag.

Answer (score 4):

You can format your webpack.config.js like this:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "library.min.js"
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    ],
};'
```

And then to build it unminified run (while in the project's main directory):

```
$ webpack
```

To build it minified run:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production webpack
```

Notes:
Make sure that for the unminified version you change the output file name to `library.js` and for the minified `library.min.js` so they do not overwrite each other.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and had to satisfy all these requirements:

- Minified + Non minified version (as in the question)
- ES6
- Cross platform (Windows + Linux).

I finally solved it as follows:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const MinifyPlugin = require("babel-minify-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = getConfiguration;

function getConfiguration(env) {
    var outFile;
    var plugins = [];
    if (env === 'prod') {
        outFile = 'mylib.dev';
        plugins.push(new MinifyPlugin());
    } else {
        if (env !== 'dev') {
            console.log('Unknown env ' + env + '. Defaults to dev');
        }
        outFile = 'mylib.dev.debug';
    }

    var entry = {};
    entry[outFile] = './src/mylib-entry.js';

    return {
        entry: entry,
        plugins: plugins,
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: __dirname
        }
    };
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "mylib.js",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npm-run-all webpack-prod webpack-dev",
        "webpack-prod": "npx webpack --env=prod",
        "webpack-dev": "npx webpack --env=dev"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    }
}
```

Then I can build by (Don't forget to `npm install` before):

```
npm run-script build
```

Comment: I got this error ERROR in unknown: Invalid typeof value

Answer (score 3):

You should export an array like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const libName = 'YourLibraryName';

function getConfig(env) {
  const config = {
    mode: env,
    output: {
      path: path.resolve('dist'),
      library: libName,
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      filename: env === 'production' ? `${libName}.min.js` : `${libName}.js`
    },
    target: 'web',
    .... your shared options ...
  };

  return config;
}

module.exports = [
  getConfig('development'),
  getConfig('production'),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two entry points in your webpack configuration, one for your normal js and the other one for minified js. Then you should output your bundle with its name, and configure UglifyJS plugin to include min.js files. See the example webpack configuration for more details:

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
   'bundle': './src/index.js',
   'bundle.min': './src/index.js',
 },

 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   filename: "[name].js"
 },

 plugins: [
   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
      minimize: true
   })
 ]
};
```

After running webpack, you will get bundle.js and bundle.min.js in your dist folder, no need for extra plugin.

Comment: deprecated explication