# Unable to set desired breakpoints in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

This is a new problem I've been encountering with Chrome DevTools lately, not sure why it's happening, but I can't seem to set normal break points in my app.

**Screencast link:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-ZQcmpdZkQ

[image]

^ I should be able to set a basic break point on line `85`, `87` or `89`. However it let's me set a un-usable breakpoint on the closing `}` on line `91`.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out! I'm using **[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)** to build up my modules into a bundle.js file. It also produces a bundle.js.map file so I can see the code in the Chrome DevTools, but I guess because it's an expanded representation of what bundle.js is, I can't correctly setup break points.

Update, just found this: [How to build minified and uncompressed bundle with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956937/how-to-build-minified-and-uncompressed-bundle-with-webpack)

Now I have a Production and Development config option to use, so I can debug correctly using the un-minified version of my main bundle.js

[image]