# Output filename for gulp/webpack task

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

I'm using webpack-stream to integrate webpack into a gulp task, as below:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
// var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task("min:webpack",
    function () {
        return gulp.src('./App/App.js')
         .pipe(webpack({
             // watch: true,
             module: {
                 entry: './App/App.js',
                 output: {
                     filename: 'App.bundle.js'
                 },
                 devtool: 'source-map'
             }
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./App'));
    });
```

Everything seems to be working as expected, except that the output file is always something like `6f7af85206d7f2f6536d.js` instead of the expected `App.bundle.js`. In other similar questions (e.g., [How to use gulp webpack-stream to generate a proper named file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074980/how-to-use-gulp-webpack-stream-to-generate-a-proper-named-file)), I've read that it was fixed effectively by specifying `output: { filename: 'something'}` in the configuration, but you can see that I'm doing that.

Any suggestions? Anything I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, dumb mistake on my part. I had the configuration specified incorrectly. This config works as expected:

```
gulp.task("min:webpack",
    function () {
        return gulp.src('./App/App.js')
         .pipe(webpack({
             // watch: true,
             entry: './App/App.js',
             output: {
                 filename: 'App.bundle.js'
             },
             devtool: 'source-map'
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./App'));
    });
```