# How to disable Uglify in react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

I tried to use Y.js (Yjs) npm package and it works in `npm start` but not `npm run build` because Uglify doesn't support ES6. So I downloaded the release of that package and include it directly. But my reactjs `npm run build` is still complaining about Uglify.

```js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.3d2ecf94.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (YArray) [./src/Pages/Collaborative/y-array/y-array.es6:12,0]
```

and my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'quickstart.js'),
  output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ["react", "es2016", "stage-2"]
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I disable Uglify in my webpack? Which line determines that it has to Uglify in building process?

**Edit:**

```js
{
  "name": "myCoolApps",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ace": "git+https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.git#master",
    "antd": "^2.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "card": "^2.2.1",
    "card-react": "^1.2.6",
    "chat-template": "0.0.22",
    "codemirror": "^5.25.0",
    "credit-card-type": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "d3": "^4.7.4",
    "firechat": "^3.0.1",
    "firepad": "^1.4.0",
    "flux": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "little-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.6",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "quill": "^1.2.3",
    "rc-calendar": "^7.6.5",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-autosuggest": "^7.0.1",
    "react-cookie": "^1.0.4",
    "react-credit-card": "^0.20.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.8.0",
    "react-event-timeline": "^1.2.2",
    "react-infinite": "^0.10.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.0.7",
    "react-list": "^0.8.3",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.12",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "seedrandom": "^2.4.2",
    "simplewebrtc": "^2.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "superagent": "^3.3.1",
    "y-array": "^10.0.6",
    "y-indexeddb": "^8.1.9",
    "y-leveldb": "0.0.1",
    "y-map": "^10.0.5",
    "y-memory": "^8.0.8",
    "y-richtext": "^9.0.8",
    "y-text": "^9.3.2",
    "y-webrtc": "^8.0.7",
    "y-websockets-client": "^8.0.15",
    "yjs": "^12.1.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Actually yea I think it uses react-script. Is there anything I can do to alter that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build minified and uncompressed bundle with webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956937/how-to-build-minified-and-uncompressed-bundle-with-webpack)

Comment: Paste your package.json please. Your config file isn't setup to use uglify. Probably the `build` script in package.json file runs webpack with `-p` option, which internally uses Uglify.

Comment: When you are comfortable with Webpack, try [Babili](http://babeljs.io/blog/2016/08/30/babili?exports=guy) to minify ES6.

Comment: I added my package.js which actually reminds me that it uses react-script which is not in my control I guess. Then I assume that maybe my build system is not using my webpack.config.js at all. What is the common usage of webpack.config.js?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? having same issue.

Comment: @MiguelMota I ended up taking out the build attribute in webpack which solves the problem for the moment but does not suit production purpose. Eventually I deprecated Yjs and wrote sync myself.

Comment: Have anyone tried this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts-plugin-no-minify

Comment: hey, could you post the answer ? how did you take out the build attribute in webpack ?

Comment: @nzaero No, I only found a temporary solution which is downloading the release build of the package and use it as common modules. This won't cause any problem since the package is pre-built release. However, eventually, I ended up writing my own module since theirs was not good enough.

Comment: @MiguelMota I found that using a pre-built release as normal module won't cause this problem. However, I ended up writing my own sync library since Yjs is not enough for my usage.

Comment: i have uninstalled npm, node everything, then, now, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what `npm run build` does, it actually runs another script, `react-scripts build`. Your project is bootstrapped with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), correct?

As you can see in the `package.json`, you also have access to a script called `eject`.

Running `npm run eject` will allow you to remove the app from the preconfigured workflow ( `webpack`, `babel`, etc ) and let you modify the workflow as you see fit.

With access to the configuration files, you can add, for example, the [babel uglify plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-uglify).

But be careful, there is a trade-off. As the docs mention

> If your project needs more customization, you can "eject" and customize it, but then you will need to maintain this configuration.