# Passing command line arguments to webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a simple webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
}
```

And I want to pass the values for `entry`and `output` through command line arguments. Is that possible and how would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`webpack.config.js` can also exports a function of env which can return a conf object. You can therefore have a webpack config (above webpack version 5) like:

```
module.exports = env => {
    return {
        entry: env.production ? "./app.js": "app-dev.js",
        output: {
          filename: "bundle.js"
        },
    }
};
```

`env` can be any name that you want. Call webpack from the command-line (or package.json) like this:

```
webpack --env=production
```

or

```
webpack --env=development
```

in the `webpack.config.js`, we get the env value is like this,

```
{ WEBPACK_BUNDLE: true, WEBPACK_BUILD: true, production: true }
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Webpack 1 right? because It throws me errors that the config file doesn't return an object

Comment: @MatiasFernandezMartinez bit late but yeah exporting a function got added in either webpack 3 or 4

Comment: It's not clear from your answer whether this `env` argument magical or we can pass arbitrary parameters, like `--paramName1=value --paramName2=value`

Comment: @MikhailBatcer Good question. It seems it has to be --env(.XXX). See [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/). Thanks to Orkun Tuzel

Comment: It should be: `entry: !!env.production ? "./app.js": "app-dev.js"`

Comment: Also, it's suggested to use: `webpack --env production` instead of: `webpack --env=production`

Answer (score 36):

You can provide custom parameters by passing environment variables on the command line. The syntax for this has changed between version 4 and 5 of Webpack. For this example, you would call:

For [Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/):

`webpack --env entry='./app.js' --env output='bundle.js'`

or

`webpack --env=entry=./app.js --env=output=bundle.js`

(Please note that although the former is the syntax from the documentation, some people have found that they need to use the latter instead)

For [Webpack 4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/):

`webpack --env.entry='./app.js' --env.output='bundle.js'`

For both versions, you can then access the environment variables in your Webpack config by doing

```
module.exports = env => ({
  entry: env.entry,
  output: {
    filename: env.output
  },
});
```

Comment: It's not clear from your answer whether this `env` argument magical or we can pass arbitrary parameters, like `--paramName1=value --paramName2=value`

Comment: THIS DOESNT WORK !! webpack --env.entry='./app.js' --env.output='bundle.js' CORRECT IS webpack --env=mode=production --env=branch=develop

Comment: @madruga This worked for Webpack 4, which was the latest version when this answer was written. The syntax has now been changed for Webpack 5. More info here: webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables. I've now updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @madruga I've updated the answer for webpack 5 for future users

Comment: @AndrewBullock why did you edit this answer? It was correct, as shown in the documentation that I linked to

Comment: The correction is what works for me and @madruga on webpack 5, the original didnt, I don't know what else to say

Comment: @AndrewBullock I'm not sure why the documentation is wrong in this case, but have integrated your edit as well so people can use whichever works for them

Answer (score 22):

You can also pass multiple key-value pairs to you config using `--env=key=value`:

```
webpack --env=mode=production --env=branch=develop
```

or (for development with webpack-dev-server):

```
webpack serve --env=mode=production --env=branch=develop
```

`webpack.config.js` would look like this:

```js
module.exports = (env) => {
  const mode = env.mode === 'prod' ? 'dev';
  const branch = env.branch ? env.branch : 'develop';

  return {
    entry: mode === 'prod' ? './app.js': 'app-dev.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: 'dist/' + branch),
    },
  }
}
```

All values passed this way are available as an object in the config which makes it easy to use them.

```json
{ 
  WEBPACK_BUNDLE: true,
  mode: 'production',
  branch: 'feature-x',
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `--env` CLI argument to pass arbitrary parameters to the config.

For example, the following command:

```sh
webpack --env entry=./entry.js --env output=./output.js
```

Will produce the following env object:

```js
{entry: './entry.js', output: './output.js'}
```

Which you can then use in your config like so:

```js
module.exports = env => ({
  entry: env.entry,
  output: {
    filename: env.output
  },
});
```

Read more here: [Webpack - Environment Variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)

Comment: The other answers in this thread have the wrong syntax and fail to explain how it can be used for arbitrary parameters. My answer covers both.

Comment: @user1934212 this answer is very clear and supports multiple variables, i'd mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [argv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argv) package and set the variables. You must do it before `module.export`.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try that. But is there no easier way, without the need of an additional package reference? After all, webpack.config.js is just javascript code.

Comment: You can pass --env=test for instance through command line and then you can export a function of env which returns an instead of directly an object https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env

Comment: You may read this then: http://justindavis.co/2014/11/24/using-command-line-arguments-in-a-node-script/

Comment: Thanks @Axnyff: the env-trick seems to work for me. If you promote it to a complete answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I just did, is this still ok for you ?

Comment: @PRAISER Could you please elaborate on this

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, in my opinion, to pass arguments is to use Node.
Webpack being the one receiving the arguments, you can **save your command line arguments in a dedicated environment variable** (which exists only within the session):

```
// webpack.config.js 
process.env.MY_APPLICATION_NAME_ARGS = JSON.stringify(process.argv)

export default {
...
```

Then in your main.js (anywhere where you want to parse them), you **retrieve your command line arguments from your dedicated environment variable**.

```
// main.js
const myArgs = JSON.parse(env.MY_APPLICATION_NAME_ARGS )
```

---

As you'll be retrieving all of the arguments you passed to Webpack, using this, you'll be able to use any node modules (like yargs for instance) painlessly to parse them (or do it manually of course).

So you'll be able to do things like these without any issues:

```
webpack ... --opt1 the_value --custom1 something
```

```
yarn run dev --opt1 the_value --custom1 something
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for those using ES Modules for Webpack configuration. When we `log` `process.argv` there is a array of arguments which we can check if the one we needed there or not.

For example:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "watch:foo": "webpack --watch --env foo"
  },
}
```

So for the command above, all we need to do is check if `process.argv` has the argument we pass:

```js
const isFoo = process.argv.indexOf('foo') > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling webpack through npm, you can simply call:

```
npm run watch --some_option=value
```

And then access the value and supply a default in `webpack.config.js` by doing:

```
const some_option = process.env.npm_config_some_option || 'defaultValue'
```