# How to add attribute/key for webpack when running to later use as check variable inside config?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to run webpack with some key like

```
./bin/webpack -stateless
```

OR

```
./bin/webpack stateless=true
```

and check later in config if stateless is true do something, if not do another thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113359/passing-command-line-arguments-to-webpack-config-js

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I expected more wider answer with example. Had to update config to use it with variable from function module.exports.