# When using Webpack and Babel, what is the best way to turn off compression?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to get more familiar with webpack.  It's my understanding that if I'm not including the uglify plugin, that `dist/bundle.js` shouldn't be minimized or compressed, but it seems like it is.

https://gist.github.com/dcvezzani/bb535a2236ef160b0769b86ec10e526b

[image]

I thought [How to build minified and uncompressed bundle with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956937/how-to-build-minified-and-uncompressed-bundle-with-webpack) might help, but perhaps webpack has changed so that the answers there are not relevant anymore.

Does webpack use its own compression?  For educational purposes, how would I run webpack so that I get my bundle, but the content is not compressed or minimized?

Comment: please share your webpack configuration file

Answer (score 1):

you may forget to set webpack.mode to "development"

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018909/5124673) mentions `module.exports.optimization.minimize` in `webpack.config.js` and setting it to `false` helped me getting the *pretty* bundle from webpack.