# react antd large production bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd, webpack-bundle

Webpack outputs a very large bundle: **1.5MB minimized**.

I import single components according to the docs, using imports 'antd/lib/...'
These are my imports:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TreeSelect from 'antd/lib/tree-select';
const TreeNode = TreeSelect.TreeNode;
import 'antd/lib/tree-select/style/css';

import moment from 'moment';
import LocaleProvider from 'antd/lib/locale-provider';

import DatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker';
import 'antd/lib/date-picker/style/css'
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

import Menu from 'antd/lib/menu';
import 'antd/lib/menu/style/css'

import Dropdown from 'antd/lib/dropdown';
import 'antd/lib/dropdown/style/css';

import Modal from 'antd/lib/modal';
import 'antd/lib/modal/style/css';

import './styles.css';
```

I'm using just 5 components. Does it make sense the bundle size is that big?
My own code is fairly small - around 15KB without minification.

**UPDATE:** After using `IgnorePlugin()` for moment, my bundle size got 300KB smaller. Still 1.5MB is very big.

Bellow is webpack config files.

webpack.config.js:

```
  const config = {
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, "index.js"),
        },
        mode: 'development',
        devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
        output: {
            path: DIST_DIR,
            filename: "bundle.js",
            publicPath: "/static/bundles/",
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".json", ".css"]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js?/,
                    include: SRC_DIR,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        babelrc: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader", "css-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        //new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ debug: true}),
      ]
    };

    module.exports = config;
```

webpack.prod.js (used to make the bundle):

```
const common = require('./webpack.config.js');
   module.exports = Object.assign(common, {
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, "index.js"),
        },
        mode: 'production',
        devtool: false,
        output: {
            publicPath: '/static/dist/',
            path: DIST_DIR,
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Hi, `moment` is huge, if you can you might want to consider using another date lib like `date-fns`https://date-fns.org/
You can also lazy load your components

Comment: It is not the first question on SO about large output bundle when using antd. Some of the components like RangePicker can also use moment lib, so it can become quite heavy

Comment: The problem is that antd DatePicker, like many other datepicker components, depends on moment.js. Second, moment is around 65KB minified. Not very small, but not huge

Comment: do you mind sharing the webpack config file?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay, updated

Comment: are you sure you are minifiying? i can't see any minification plugin used? you can use uglifyjs plugin

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay that plugin is used by default when using `mode: production`

Answer (score 1):

Some of the components of Antd date Time functionality like **RangePicker** also use moment.js lib, so it can become quite heavy.

UPD:

try to optimize it using plugins:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    screw_ie8: true,
    conditionals: true,
    unused: true,
    comparisons: true,
    sequences: true,
    dead_code: true,
    evaluate: true,
    if_return: true,
    join_vars: true,
  },
  comments: false,
  sourceMap: true,
  minimize: true,
  exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi],
}),
new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
```

Comment: and how he decreases the size of that bundle? Please, complete your answer.

Comment: Can you explain how it works? And I'm getting an error `"webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead."`

Comment: @user3599803 Webpack uses a series of optimization plugins just look over them. When it comes to minimization you can also use different minifiers but uglify.js is the most common one. Don't know why they have removed it from webpack, here is the solution for it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018909/10098471

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Antd 4 is out! It solves the SVG icon problem and it's 228kb smaller than the 3.x version. Updating to version 4.0.X is gonna bring a massive reduction in our bundle size.

**OLD ANSWER**

At the moment, a huge part of antd dist is svg icons. [16.3% to be exact (current version)](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=antd@3.22.0).

I believe we don't have any officials ways to deal with icons already, but a workaround exists. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011#issuecomment-423173228).

Thus, if you remove this and moment locale you can reduce the lib size about 20%.

They are working on reducing the lib size in the antd 4 for, which it's already on alpha (with already less 130kb minified).